# WSO2 Dev Studio 3.8 does not start, nor attach to WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2

I went to wso2.com site today and downloaded the WSO2 EI 6.0 server and the Developer Studio 3.8. I tried creating a new project and starting WSO2 EI server from Eclipse. It cannot start the EI server due to a bug in the tooling. The issue is reported here: https://github.com/wso2/devstudio-tooling-ei/issues/6

Then I tried to use the remote server option, but it cannot connect to it either due to another bug in tooling. It seems the 3.8 version is broken.

I was hoping wso2 dev community is quite mature to deliver stable releases. But having such basic features broken is quite worrying.

Could someone recommend a combination of EI and Dev Studio that is proven to work?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the EI 6.1.1 version with the WSO2 Developer Studio 3.8 version.